# Singular or plural verb after a list of single activities?

Tags: grammar, phrasing

In the following sentence, which one is correct? "requires" or "require"?

> Reading all recent papers, relating them together, and finally drawing a conclusion from them **require(s)** hard work.

"require(s)" refer to all activities of "reading", "relating", and "drawing". Should we see all these activities as a single set of activities and use a singular verb? Or see them as separate activities and use a plural verb?

Comment: Can you answer this yourself? ARE THEY 3 phases in a single activity, or 3 separate and distinct activities?

Comment: They are 3 phases in a single activity.

Comment: Then we treat the whole activity as one… and the verb is singular

Answer (score 1):

Both these sentences are correct but they mean different things:

> reading, relating and drawing require hard work

This means that each of the three tasks requires hard work.

> reading, relating and drawing requires hard work

This means that doing all three together as one process requires hard work, but individually they could be easy.

But you included the word *finally* which so we know you are definitely describing a single three-step process and therefore the singular verb *requires* is correct

> reading, relating and finally drawing requires hard work